# Drawing a fullhouse from a standard deck

Tags: combinatorics

I saw this:
[Probability of getting a full house](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808314/probability-of-getting-a-full-house)
and the top answer makes sense to me.
However, why can't I also do this?
Pick a suite. $\binom{4}{1}$.
Take 3 cards from that suite. $\binom{13}{3}$.
Pick a different suite. $\binom{3}{1}$.
Take 2 cards from that suite. $\binom{13}{2}$.
So desired hands are $\binom{4}{1}\binom{13}{3}\binom{3}{1}\binom{13}{2}$.
This is much larger than their answer.

Their answer is $\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}3\binom{12}1\binom{4}2$.

Comment: But that will not satisfy the condition for a full house

Comment: I think you're confused as to what a full house is; simply google "full house cards" and see, *Three matching cards of one rank and two matching cards of another rank*. You're making that *Three matching cards of one suite and two matching cards of another suite*, which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not cards from same suite like heart or spade, it's same type, like $2, 7,$ J, K, etc. so $13$ types.